# How to enable/disable all buttons in React App using a switch/toggle button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to make a switch/toggle button that disables all the buttons in the app, and enables them when clicked on AND the user types in the correct password

```
handleToggleChange() {
    var elements=document.getElementsByClassName('MuiButtonBase-root');
    var i;
    if (this.state.lock ===  false) {
        this.setState({lock: true});
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].disabled = false;
        }
    } else {
        this.setState({lock: false});
        for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my ToggleButton Code

```
                       <ToggleButtonGroup onChange={this.handleToggleChange}>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                label={<Typography variant="caption">Unlock</Typography>}
                                control={<ToggleButton
                                        id="togglebutton"
                                        size="small"
                                        value="false" 
                                        color="secondary"
                                        style={{right: 5}}
                                        selected={this.state.lock === false ? false : true}
                                    >
                                    <CheckIcon /></ToggleButton>}/>
                        </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

The problem is that it seems to be working, but they don't actually get disabled, despite the disable property appearing when I go into the debugger.
[disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNNNM.png)

And then the disabled property disappears when the button is unchecked. [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ11b.png)

I'm fairly new to javascript so I'm not even sure if this is the way I'm supposed to be doing something like this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely _not_ the way you should be doing this, at least not in a MV* framework context.  If you were not using a MV* framework it might be acceptable to do it this way, but in a MV* framework doing any sort of direct DOM manipulation is generally considered to be an antipattern under 99% of scenarios.  In an MV*, rather than directly manipulating the DOM, you create a model and bind it to a view, and then your logic simply updates the model and the view will update automatically via the binding.  This is probably related to why it is not really working.

Comment: @AlexanderNied so what function/pattern should I use to change the property of every button in my app, all at the same time?

Comment: Added an answer with a working example-- see below.

Answer (score 0):

Simply achieving this at a single level with props is relatively easy.  However, for app-wide state that needs to be injected at any level, you most likely want to leverage [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which is a React lifecycle-connected state that is injectable at any level.  Below is an example using the [`useContext` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to create a button that can be used anywhere at any level that will automatically pick up if the global disabled state has been toggled:

```js
// Get a hook function
const { useContext, useState } = React;

const GlobalDisabledStateContext = React.createContext({ disableUI: false });

const App = () => {
  const [disableUI, setDisableUI] = useState(false);
  return (
    <GlobalDisabledStateContext.Provider value={{disableUI}}>
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <label for="toggleDisableUI">
          Toggle Disabled UI
          <input type="checkbox" name="toggleDisableUI" id="toggleDisableUI" checked={disableUI} onChange={() => setDisableUI(!disableUI)} />
        </label>
        <h2>Below is a button wired into the app context state, which can be used at any level without wiring app state through props</h2>
        <AppStateConnectedButton onClick={() => console.log('hi')}>
          Click Me
        </AppStateConnectedButton>
      </div>
    </GlobalDisabledStateContext.Provider>
  );
}

const AppStateConnectedButton = (props) => {
  const { disableUI } = useContext(GlobalDisabledStateContext);
  return (<button disabled={disableUI} {...props} />);
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

As I noted in the comments, any sort of DOM manipulation in the context of an MV* framework like React or Angular is an antipattern under 99% of scenarios.  The entire idea of MV* frameworks is that you create a data model, bind it to a view, and the all your logic is to update the data model and let the library handle updating the view.  If you ever find yourself interrogating or changing DOM in an MV* framework you are likely doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try. In the meantime, i've added a state called lock to my main file, that gets toggled true/false using a button. And then gave every other button on that page the property disabled={this.state.lock}. These ones get disabled in the way that I want, but how would I access this variable from the other tabs on my app so that i can do the same for every other button on every tab.

Comment: Adding local state is a great way to manage it for a single page, correct.  To access it across various app pages at various depths, that's what React Context is for.  Wrap the provider around your entire app, and then either leverage the `useContext` hook individually as needed to get access to the context value or create a component pre-hooked into context as shown in my example.  This is all under the assumption, I suppose, that you are using React as a SPA-- if you are _not_, then this becomes a different question.